# CSS3 Media Query not affecting class width

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm working with CSS media queries for responsive web design. To keep them organized and easy to access, I'm declaring all of the media queries at the top of my CSS document, like this:

```
* {margin:0 auto; padding: 0;}
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; font: normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #FFF; background: url(../img/defaultNav.jpg); background-repeat: repeat-x;}
h1 {font-size: 5.75em; font-weight: 800; text-align: center}
h2 {font-size: 2.5em; font-weight: 300; text-align: center; line-height: 50px;}
h3 {font-size: 2.5em; font-weight: 100; line-height:50px; color: #666;}
h4 {font-size: 1.25em; font-weight: 100; color: #999; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom:18px;}
p {font-size: 1em; color: #999;}
a {color: #999; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

@media screen and (min-width: 1700px) { 
                                        h1 {font-size: 6.2em;}
                                        h2 h3 {font-size: 3.5em;}
                                        h4 {font-size: 2.5em;}
                                        p {font-size: 2em;}
                                        /*.content {max-width: 80em;}*/
                                      }
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {  /*.column {float: none; width: auto;}*/ }
@media screen and (min-width: 681px) {  .mobileBar, .nav {display: none;}   }
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {  .header .title h1 {font-size: 2.5em;}   h2 {font-size: 1.5em;}  .headerSmall .title h1 {font-size: 2.5em;}  }
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {  p {text-align: left;}   }
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
                                        * {text-align: left;}
                                        h1 { font-size: 2.5em;}
                                        h2 {font-size: 1.2em;}
                                        h3 {font-size: 1.6em; line-height: normal; text-align: center;}
                                        h4 {font-size: 1.4em; text-align: center;}
                                        .content .contentTitles img {display: none;}
                                     }
```

The queries work just fine, except for the two I have commented out above. (under the first two queries) Those two queries only work if I write them under the classes I am trying to affect i.e.:

```
.content {
margin:auto;
padding:1em 2em;
max-width:35.75em;
height:inherit;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1700px) {    .content {max-width: 80em;}    }
```

I don't understand why it is doing this. I've tried researching here on stack and just general Google searching but I can't find any results. It's really frustrating because I like keeping my code organized. If anyone has any idea why this is happening I'd appreciate the help. I'm also testing on the latest versions of Safari and Firefox and Safari iOS if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `max-width: 35.75em` in the `.content` rule is **overriding** the rule from the media query. Because it comes later. That's how the cascade works.

How you group and order media query rules is completely up to you, but they don't get some kind of special priority over rules coming later, and can be overridden just like any other CSS rule.

Your browser's style inspector will show you exactly what styles are being applied and/or overridden. Do you know how to use it?

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I just assumed media queries overrode anything else like they had a priority.  I knew about safari's web inspector but I just googled it and didnt know it had so many features. Thanks for the help